# Magento 2 Catalog Rule Condtions

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, uicomponent, catalog-rules

I am trying to implement Magento 2 catalog rule condtions in a custom module Ui Component form. Below is the field set:

```
<htmlContent name="block_promo_catalog_edit_tab_conditions" sortOrder="20">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Conditions</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <wrapper>
            <canShow>true</canShow>
            <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
        </wrapper>
    </settings>
    <block class="Magento\CatalogRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Catalog\Edit\Tab\Conditions" name="promo_catalog_edit_tab"/>
</htmlContent>
```

I am getting below error:

> Fatal error: Method
>   Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an
>   exception, caught Error: Call to a member function
>   getConditionsFieldSetId() on null in
>   /vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0

Any idea how to fix this one.?

If we implement the same field for **Sales Rule** it works fine with the following code without error:

```
<fieldset name="conditions">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Conditions</item>
        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">127</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<container name="conditions_apply_to" >
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <htmlContent name="html_content">
        <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Magento\SalesRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\Conditions</argument>
    </htmlContent>

</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this file in Block folder

Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Tab

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;

class Conditions extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
/**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
 */
protected $_rendererFieldset;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions
 */
protected $_conditions;

private $ruleFactory;

/**
 * Initialize dependencies.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
 * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
    $this->_conditions = $conditions;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}


private function getRuleFactory()
{
    if ($this->ruleFactory === null) {
        $this->ruleFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory');
    }
    return $this->ruleFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function getTabClass()
{
    return null;
}



/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('Conditions');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return __('Conditions');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}

protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('\Magento\CatalogRule\Controller\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CATALOG_RULE_ID');

    if (!$model) {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
        $model = $this->getRuleFactory()->create();
        $model->load($id);
    }
    $fieldsetId = 'conditions_fieldset';
    $formName = 'catalog_rule_form';

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');

    $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
        'catalog_rule/promo_catalog/newConditionHtml/form/' . $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName),
        ['form_namespace' => $formName]
    );

    $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate('Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml')
                        ->setNewChildUrl($newChildUrl)
                        ->setFieldSetId($model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName));

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        $fieldsetId,
        [
            'legend' => __(
                'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
            )
        ]
    )->setRenderer(
        $renderer
    );


    $fieldset->addField(
        'conditions',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'conditions', 'label' => __('Conditions'), 'title' => __('Conditions')]
    )->setRule(
        $model
    )->setRenderer(
        $this->_conditions
    );

    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

}

And Add this code in layout edit file

```
<referenceContainer name="left">
    <block class="Vender\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Chartlist\Edit\Tabs" name="vender_module_edit_tabs">
        <block class="Vender\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Chartlist\Edit\Tab\Conditions" name="vender_module_tab_conditions"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">conditions_section</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">vender_module_tab_conditions</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```